# Sorting an arraylist based on objects value in another arraylist in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an issue with sorting an Array List.
In a class i have two Array Lists of different objects, we can call the objects Foo and Bar.

```
public class Foo() {
   int value;
   //Some other fields, and setters and getters.
}

public class Bar() {
   int id;
   //Same here...
}
```

So the list fooList can be totally scrambeled. Say that i have 16 Foos, but Foo with value 5 can be on index 13 and so on.

What i'm trying to do is to order barList to match fooList after these values. 
If Foo with value 5 is on index 13, i want Bar with value 5 to be on index 13.
My last attempt was this, but no success.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> positions = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<fooList.size();i++){
    positions.put(foo.get(i).getValue, i);
}
Collections.sort(barList, new Comparator<Bar>(){
    public int compare(Bar obj1, Bar obj2){
        return positions.get(barList.indexOf(obj1)) -
 positions.get(barList.indexOf(obj2));
    }
});
```

Does anybody have a clue how to do this in an efficient way?

Comment: Create a comparable class `FooBar`. It holds a reference to a `Foo` and another to a `Bar`. It is comparable with other `FooBar` instances based on your criteria.

Comment: And what about sorting both lists from 0 to limit? Would it work for you?

Comment: Should not you do `positions.get( obj1.getId() )`?

Comment: Can you explain the intended behaviour when Foo (value) and Bar (id) values are disjoint?

Comment: In other words - Can Bar have an id that is not there in Foo?

Comment: Define "efficient". What do you want to optimize for?

Comment: @user7 no Bar can not have ha different id. There is always 16 Bars and 16 Foos.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks will try this!

Comment: @nlopez No unfortunately. I want to keep the order of fooList and match barList after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using the index of an element in `barList` to look into the map `positions`.

This should help you

```
Collections.sort(barList, new Comparator<Bar>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Bar o1, Bar o2) {
        return positions.get(o1.getId()) - positions.get(o2.getId());
    }
});
```

This can be simplified with a one-liner

```
Collections.sort(barList, Comparator.comparingInt(bar -> positions.get(bar.getId())));
```

---

Basically, the problem boils down to this:

Given two lists of integers A = {a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub>} and B = {b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, ...b<sub>m</sub>}, sort the list B based on the position of occurrence of the element in the first list, A.

For two elements *x*, *y* in B

- *x > y*, if *x* appears before *y* in A.
- *x < y*, if *x* appears after *y* in A.
- *x = y*, if *x* = *y*

So, the comparator function for `Bar` has to compare the position at which a particular element has appeared in `Foo` (based on the above).

**NOTE:** This assumes (as you have said) that there is **no element** in `Bar` that is not there in `Foo`. (The elements in `Bar` are a subset of the elements in `Foo`).

Comment: Could you explain why this is the solution?

Comment: @EmilSundvall Have you made sure Foo does not have any `value` that is not there in Bar (`Bar.id`). Also, make sure there are no nulls in the Bar list.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first index items of the `barList` on values so that it would be possible to quickly find a `Bar` instance with the appropriate value. Then use it to transform the `fooList` into the new `barList`. Something along the lines:

```
Map<Integer, Bar> barMap = barList
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors
        .toMap(
            Bar::getValue,
            Function.identity());
barList = fooList
    .stream()
    .map(Foo::getValue)
    .map(barMap::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I think this must be as optimal as it gets in terms of time. In the expence of memory, you have to build a `barMap` here.